# "https://github.com/scandipwa/base-theme" not able to run after install nodemodule

Tags: magento2, react

is there anybody who can help me with this error ?
I am working as a react developer, as per the magento official docs, scandipwa base-theme is configured with react so I tried that.

After cloning the "https://github.com/scandipwa/base-theme" I installed nodemodule but when I am trying to run `npm run watch`,
At 1st compile i got

> scandipwa-base@1.0.0 watch /home/chiranjivi/Desktop/base-theme
> webpack-dev-server --config ./src/config/webpack.development.config.js
>
> ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://scandipwa.local/
>
> ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
>
> ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from
> /home/chiranjivi/Desktop/base-theme
>
> ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html Browserslist: caniuse-lite
> is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`

After that, it's throwing this error :

> ERROR in
> ./src/app/component/MyAccountTabListItem/MyAccountTabListItem.style.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./src/app/component/MyAccountTabListItem/MyAccountTabListItem.style.scss)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js):

```
Error: 
      Something wrong with provided resources.
      Make sure 'options.resources' is String or Array of Strings.
    
      at Object.module.exports (/home/chiranjivi/Desktop/base-theme/node_modules/sass-resources-loader/lib/loader.js:71:18)"
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You must never run ScandiPWA without Magento itself. For installation, please use following docs: https://docs.scandipwa.com/#/?id=ready-to-try

You have two main options:
- Composer installation on existing M2 instance
- Docker installation on Linux

- Optionally you can develop ScandiPWA without running Magento server on your local host. See instructions for running "with remote server".

And remember, ScandiPWA is a Magento theme, not a headless Magento Frontend. So, you must run it along side of Magento. It also requires additional modules on Magento side. Refer to installation on existing Magento instance for more information.

I will also update the docs on ScandiPWA GitHub, so nobody will be confused anyone.